# How to project the result of a QueryTask in ArcGIS Javascript API?

Tags: arcgis-10.0, coordinate-system, javascript, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript

I have created a web map that displays point features based on a given date range. Our current projection is Oregon State Plane South. My boss wants me to change the map to use a Web Mercator projection. I am loading our web mercator basemap fine, but I'm having trouble projecting and displaying the points. What is the most efficient way of doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The javascript API (as well as flex and silverlight) uses the REST API.

The REST API [query operation](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisserver/10.0/apis/rest/query.html) allows an output spatial reference to be specified.

Comment: Thanks! It looks like I asked the question too soon, as I figured it out just after asking it. Hopefully others find it useful.